# Ошибка "Class TForm1 not found" при старте Delphi Android приложения. Само приложение работает

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

Написал простое Android приложение в Delphi с простой формой для логина. Проблема в том, что когда я запускаю его на смартфоне, приложение стартует нормально, но показывает сообщение об ошибке "Class TFormLogin not found" (примерно через 100мс после того как появляется FormLogin). Несмотря на это, FormLogin создается и работает как задумано. После клика по ok на сообщении, приложение продолжает нормально работать.

[image]

Что значит сообщение "Class TFormLogin not found" и как его убрать?

P.S. Т.к. я уже решил проблему, скажу, что тут замешан StyleBook.

---

В комментариях попросили сделать MCVE. Ошибка воспроизводится в новом пустом multi-platform проекте, без какого-либо кода в  PAS или DPR. Такого FMX достаточно:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  StyleName = 'bg'
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 480
  ClientWidth = 640
  StyleBook = StyleBook1
  StyleLookup = 'bg'
  FormFactor.Width = 320
  FormFactor.Height = 480
  FormFactor.Devices = [Desktop]
  DesignerMasterStyle = 0
  object StyleBook1: TStyleBook
    Styles = <
      item
      end>
    Left = 304
    Top = 224
  end
end
```

Comment: Этот же вопрос на английском: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54230787

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось, что эта ошибка из StyleBook (и да, её текст следовало бы сделать более толковым).

Сообщение об ошибке вызвано тем, что TFormLogin использует StyleBook и имеет указанное свойство StyleLookup и StyleName в FMX, в то время, как в самом StyleBook такой стиль (StyleName) отсутствовал.

P.S. Что меня озадачивает, если одно из свойств StyleLookup или StyleName пустое, то все работает. И только если оба поля заполнены - сообщение об ошибке.